# Can't add VirtualPage as allowed children

Tags: silverstripe

I have created a holder page `KochiHolder` as below and performed a database rebuild successfully. I have set the `$allowed_children` of `KochiHolder` to only accept `KochiPage` or `VirtualPage`.

In the CMS I cannot create a `VirtualPage` under a `KochiHolder` page.

Why is `$allowed_children` not working correctly? How do I allow `VirtualPage` to be created as a sub page of `KochiHolder`?

**KochiHolder**

```php
class KochiHolder extends Page {

    private static $db = array(   
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Photo' => 'Image'
    );

    private static $can_be_root = false;

    private static $allowed_children = array('KochiPage', 'VirtualPage');           

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();        

        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Images", new UploadField('Photo'));

        return $fields;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you run `?flush` after you added VirtualPage to $allowed_children?

Comment: @thomaspaulson, if you found my answer helpful, please mark it as accepted. That way it can signal to visitors that come across the same issue to know there are known solutions for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of debugging of [`CMSPageAddController`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/blob/3.1/code/controllers/CMSPageAddController.php#L132-L178) (more specifically, the `doAdd` action) that Silverstripe uses for the "Add Page" screen in the CMS, I believe I found the root cause of the problem.

So the following error seems to be occurring: `Page type "Page" not allowed as child of this parent page` (well, that is the error I was getting in my test)

In the `SiteTree` class, it has a [`validate`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/blob/3.1/code/model/SiteTree.php#L1592-L1628) function which checks what the allowed children are. One of the checks for this is [unrolling `VirtualPage` to the page it is a virtual of](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/blob/3.1/code/model/SiteTree.php#L1601). (There is probably a little more to it than that - I need to do more investigating)

Good news is that you can override this functionality however it isn't great. Basically, because your class extends `Page` which extends `SiteTree`, if you specify your own `validate` function on `Page` (as `VirtualPage` extends `Page` too) you would be able to override the functionality.

In my tests, I used the following:

```
public function validate()
{
    $result = parent::validate();

    if ($this instanceof VirtualPage)
    {
        $newResult = new ValidationResult();

        $items = $result->messageList();
        foreach ($items as $key => $value)
        {
            if ($key != 'ALLOWED_CHILDREN')
            {
                $newResult->error($value, $key);
            }
        }

        return $newResult;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

It isn't perfect and it makes some assumptions (eg. error codes are assumed for all items in the `messageList` but [that isn't always the case](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/model/ValidationResult.php#L31-L53)). I haven't done heaps of testing with it but it does work for my recreation of your particular scenario.